# Как в Yii2 правильно приводить данные к нужному типу при сохранении в базе?

Tags: yii2, mongodb

Из полей формы на сайте всегда приходит информация в виде текста, даже если я указываю в модели

```
public function rules() {
return [
    [['field'], 'integer'],
];
}
```

преобразование типа происходит только если сделать так:

```
public function behaviors() {
        'typecast' => [
            'class' => AttributeTypecastBehavior::className(),
            'attributeTypes' => [
                'field' => AttributeTypecastBehavior::TYPE_INTEGER,
            ],
            'typecastAfterValidate' => true,
            'typecastBeforeSave' => false,
            'typecastAfterFind' => false,
}
```

так и должно быть или я чтото не так делаю? По моей логике, указав в rules тип система должна привести **field** к типу INTEGER, и так же сохранить в базе, а нет, сохраняет как текст!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В рамках Yii2 логично приводить в типу в правилах валидации с помощью filter:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['field'], 'filter', 'intval'],
        [['field'], 'integer'],
    ];
}
```

Тогда при валидации перед проверкой на число, твое значение приведется к int.

Comment: при сохранении получаю Setting unknown property: yii\validators\FilterValidator::0, что не так?

Comment: спасибо, разобрался, работает

Answer (score 1):

```
public function beforeValidate()
{
    parent::beforeValidate();
    $this->field = (int) $this->field;

    return true;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: спасибо, это работает